# SharpSpring tracking script in AMP page

Tags: amp-html

I've a tracking script from Sharpspring which I need to integrate into an AMP page. The script is like in the screen below.

[image]

The custom script tag not allowed in AMP page. So how can I integrate this script?

Thank you.

Comment: If the tracking doesn't exist as a amp-module and you can't solve it using a tracking pixel or something else scriptless, you can't.

Comment: Thank you @SebastianSpeitel